# Amounts of Potassium Sorbate, Calcium Propinate or Ascorbic Acid as preservative in dough

Tags: bread, dough

I bake homemade wheat bread, but after a few days it becomes moldy (dark), even the dough in the refrigerator. I understand that calcium propionate and potassium sorbate are safe preservatives, but I don't have any idea what amounts to use.

Normally I use to work with a whole bag (25 Pounds) of wheat flour in a Hobart commercial mixer. [This SA question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64797/how-much-calcium-propionate-should-i-use-as-a-bread-preservative) answers how much calcium propionate to use.

But: Can I use potassium sorbate as well? Can I change any of those two products by ascorbic acid (Vitamin C) or should I use all of 3? What amounts should I use then?

Comment: Before starting to add food preservatives, have you checked what's your room temperature / fridge temperature with a thermometer? Also, how much is _a few days_: 2, 3 or 10? Is the air perhaps too humid? Those factors might make a difference in the shelf life of your dough.

Comment: also, check this question https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/62280/bread-preservation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No to the potassium sorbate, because it will inhibit yeast growth.  (Use potassium sorbate as a preservative in chemically-leavened goods such as cakes, cookies... even non-leavened things such as pie crusts.  Just don't use it with yeast.)

As for the calcium propionate, check my answer for details on the page to which you provided a link.

Yes, you can use ascorbic acid along with calcium propionate -- but be sure you want the effects it will have on your dough -- such as finer, softer crumb structure and shorter rise/proof times.  If you're after a sturdier, more open crumb, ascorbic acid might not be for you.  If you want to try it anyway, start with the bare minimum amount.  I have read suggested amounts of anywhere from 15 to 80 ppm (0.0015 to 0.0080%) of the flour weight.  I've had good luck with about 70 ppm (0.007 baker's percent) -- or roughly 1/16 of a teaspoon of the particular ascorbic acid per pound of flour that I have on hand.  That would work out to just a shade over 1½ teaspoons per 25-pound bag of flour!  I recommend weighing (**especially** when working with large batches that can become expensive mistakes -- and be careful; a little goes a very long way!